# SharePoint 2013 Add Version History link to search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SP 2013 when viewing a document library after clicking on ... for a specific document there is a "Version History" link on the context menu.

I have already created a custom display template for my hover panel. What do I need to add to the hover panel to show a "Version History" link in it?

Thanks for any help.